# Adaptive menu with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created navgation in my html and I want to make this adaptive: when the width is lower than 764px remove this `<nav>` and add on icon-button, which opens my nav in drop-down menu in column-mode.
I use flexbox and want to use clear JS.

Second problem is that my drop-down menu doesn't takes space when opens, should I use something like `position: ;` or other?

HTML:

```html
<header>
    <nav class="header__nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar--wrapper">
                <div class="openButton" id="openButton">Open the menu!</div>
                <ul class="navbar" id="navbar">
                    <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">element7</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">element2</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">element3</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">element4</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">element5</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">element6</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__link"><a href="#">element7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<script src="scripts/menu.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: inherit;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* HEADER ============ */

nav.header__nav {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #1156ed;
}

.contact-number {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.contact__row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.contact-text {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.navbar--wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.openButton {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 764px) {
    .openButton {
        display: flex;
    }
    ul.navbar {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    ul.navbar:active {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    ul.navbar>li {
        display: flex;
    }
}

ul.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

li.nav__link {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

li.nav__link:hover {
    background-color: #0f3ea3;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
}

li.nav__link > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

JS:

```js
window.onload function() {
    var navbarStyle = getComputedStyle(navbar);

    openButton.onclick function() {
        if (navbarStyle.display == "none") {
            navbar.classList.add("active");
            this.innerHTML = "Close";
        } else {
            navbar.classList.remove("active");
            this.innerHTML = "Open";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like I've solved the problem, but there is another problem! I move part with @media in the end of code, it makes my <ul> got dissapeared, but it doesn't opens when I click the button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the JS code, that's the reason:
JS:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("navbar");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "navbar";
    }
}
```

Moreover, I changed height of the element so now they are open with the normal height